# 'GeckoButtonElement' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: vb.net

Updated geckofx45 to 60 as in browser keep showing message like "this browser is not supported anymore please update your browser" and once I updated my solution references, I get 12 errors :(
I tried to look here if I did not find similar issue but for me it doesn't helped.
I tried also update framework from 4.5 to 4.6 then to 4.7.2 even more errors like 102 !

So I'm not sure why this happens, but I know I need the latest gecko browser it order to load website correctly and get rid of message "update your browser"

[https://ibb.co/PD1tY5g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqekC.png)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Because I have the same problem with `GeckoButtonElement`

Comment: @firefalcon no I give up and choose selenium instead